# Facebook deep linking not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, single-sign-on, deep-linking

I have a problem with Facebook integration in my application. I am working on giving the user an option to post his latest update to Facebook.

I can successfully post the message the Facebook, but I have problems with the "via MY_APP" section - the MY_APP is not clickable from my iPhone. The name of the app appears correctly, the message is published as I intended it to be, but when looking at the post from Facebook on iPhone, users are not able to click the name of my application in order to get them redirected to the AppStore or the application itself, depending on whether they have it installed or not. That usually works on my iPhone for other iOS apps.

When viewing the Facebook profile from a computer, my application name is clickable and it takes me to the app's community page (I set it up from MY_APP->Edit app->Settings->Advanced->App Page as I though it was required in order to solve the problem on the iPhone, but it didn't solve anything).

On the Settings->Basic screen I configured everything correctly (I think):

Native iOS App is chosen as integration type, and the options are as follows:

iOS Bundle ID: my bundle ID (checked it, correct)
iPhone AppStore ID: the ID (checked it, correct)
iPad AppStore ID: the ID (checked it, correct)
iOS SSO: Enabled
iOS Native Deep Linking: Enabled
URL Scheme Suffix: I left it blank

I also edited settings under Settings->Advanced for Authentication tab:
I changed the App Type from Web to Native/Desktop and disabled the sandbox mode.

Do you guys have any idea what is preventing me from being able to click on the application name when viewing the post from iPhone?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's how it is intended to be.

Comment: I doubt it, other applications let me click on their name and take me to the app store if I don't have them installed, or start the application in case I have it installed.
That's the behavior I'd like to achieve.

Comment: My bet is that it has something to do with your app center settings. Maybe you should follow this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/). See also [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/09/introducing-the-app-center/) for more information.

Comment: Hi Lego, I didn't have AppCenter set up before so I did it now. Unfortunately the problem persists, I can click the APP_NAME from Facebook on desktop, but I cannot click on it from the iPhone, it is just plain, gray text.. Also, I don't know if it means anything, but I haven't used my App Secret anywhere, I use just the AppID to initialize Facebook in AppDelegate, and then publish the status.

Comment: Settings->Advanced for Authentication tab: Keep this at Web

Yes, this is confusing but it's due to some legacy settings and you want to keep it to Web.